# i was trying to make a spring jdbc project but when i tried to run it got this exception

Tags: spring, jdbc

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [SpringDispatcher] threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
```

Exception:

> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
>         org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>         java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>         java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>         org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>         java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

Comment: Can you add more details in the question?

Comment: https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-with-jdbctemplate-example

Comment: you can refer this link what i have tried is to modify some fields according to my requirements otherwise the whole project is same

Comment: the same URL which you mentioned has at least 100  different responses, it would be hard to help with so little information.

As of there is nothing shich seems to related with jdbc

Answer (score 0):

i read my console and found that the main reason behind this failure was ambiquity in @RequestMapping in my Home.controller so i updated my annotation and then my Homepage start loading just fine